# Go uint8 to float32

Tags: math, go

I'm trying to learn Go and working on a rain intensity tool. 
For this tool I have to make a calculation like this:

```
var intensity float32
intensity = 10^((value−109)÷32)
```

The value is an `uint8`, ranging from 0 to 255. The intensity variable is a float.

However, Go tells me that

> cannot use 10 ^ (value - 109) / 32 (type uint8) as type float32 in assignment

How can I solve this?

Comment: Need an explicit conversion first, i.e. `math.Pow(10, float32(value−109) / 32)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no `÷` operator in Go and `^` is a bitwise XOR, you need to use `Pow` functions from `math` package
2. Go is very strict about type conversions, so it disallows implicit type conversions in many cases (so unsigned integer to floating point is not valid), so you need explicitly convert it with `type(expr)`, i.e. `float32(1)`

That said:

```
intensity = float32(math.Pow(10, float64((value - 109) / 32)))
// - OR -
intensity = float32(math.Pow10(int((value - 109) / 32)))
```

Comment: Thank you, after changing one bracket your example workt perffectly for me `math.Pow(10, (float64(value) - 109) / 32)`